# How to delete an object (created with a GeneXus Extension not installed) in a GeneXus Knowledge Base

Tags: mdd, genexus

I imported an export with objects generated with a GeneXus extension I don't have installed. 
**How find and delete this object from my KB?**

When I open the KB apear this error:

### TITLE: Open Knowledge Base

Knowledge Base at 'C:\Models\101\MT1' contains items that GeneXus doesn't know how to handle and will therefore be inaccessible.

It is likely that the Knowledge Base has been previously opened with a GeneXus installation which had extensions that are not present in the current one.

These items are:
* 'K2BToolsAuditSettings' - 'K2 BTools Audit Settings' (GUID 75a2b955-749a-3f29-99e0-aec666f802a0)
    Provided by 'AuditUI' (GUID bf5ce710-6999-4e70-9ed8-a8ac4017827d).

Working on this Knowledge Base may lose information related to these unknown items.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that involves creating a GX extension just to delete the object? Or would you like some sql sentence that you can run over the KB DB to clean the mess?

Comment: I would like to solve the problem without Export/Import the KB. If the solution involve SQL sentences it's Ok, but I prefer use the GeneXus UI to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Executing this script, i resolved this problem.

delete from Entity where EntityTypeId = (select EntityTypeId from EntityType where EntityTypeName = 'K2BToolsAuditSettings')
delete from EntityVersion where EntityTypeId = (select EntityTypeId from EntityType where EntityTypeName = 'K2BToolsAuditSettings')
delete from EntityVersionComposition where ComponentEntityTypeId = (select EntityTypeId from EntityType where EntityTypeName = 'K2BToolsAuditSettings')
delete from EntityVersionComposition where CompoundEntityTypeId = (select EntityTypeId from EntityType where EntityTypeName = 'K2BToolsAuditSettings')
delete from ModelCrossReference where FromEntityTypeId = (select EntityTypeId from EntityType where EntityTypeName = 'K2BToolsAuditSettings')
delete from ModelCrossReference where ToEntityTypeId = (select EntityTypeId from EntityType where EntityTypeName = 'K2BToolsAuditSettings')
delete from ModelEntityHistory where EntityTypeId = (select EntityTypeId from EntityType where EntityTypeName = 'K2BToolsAuditSettings')
delete from ModelEntityOutput where EntityTypeId = (select EntityTypeId from EntityType where EntityTypeName = 'K2BToolsAuditSettings')
delete from ModelEntityProperty where EntityTypeId = (select EntityTypeId from EntityType where EntityTypeName = 'K2BToolsAuditSettings')
delete from ModelEntityToTable where EntityTypeId = (select EntityTypeId from EntityType where EntityTypeName = 'K2BToolsAuditSettings')
delete from ModelEntityVersion where EntityTypeId = (select EntityTypeId from EntityType where EntityTypeName = 'K2BToolsAuditSettings')